# Access token attribute in similarity class

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

How would would one access a token attribute of a term in a custom implementation of the similarity class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ComputeNorm(...) method in the Similarity class has a FieldInvertState parameter that has an AttributeSource property that should do the trick.